# How to program a manifest file for a chrome extention

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upload a chrome extension, but I'm being returned an error that my json file has a syntax error, but I can't figure out what it is. Here's the file:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Drive to Tumblr",
 "version": "1",
 "description": "Posts files from google drive to tumblr",
 "icons": "Extention_Logo_48x48.png"
 },
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Drive to Tumblr",
   "default_icon":  "Extention_Logo_19x19.png",                                
   "default_popup": "button.html"
 }
}
```

I'm using the given syntax on the chrome developers guide, so could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have more close braces than open braces.  I'd start there.

Comment: Well I fixed that and feel kinda stupid for it, but now I'm getting the error "manifest.json:9:5: unexpected char."

Comment: Linters/validators are your friends: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the 1st close brace that you have because the `browser_action` is still part of the main manifest. This should work:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Drive to Tumblr",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Posts files from google drive to tumblr",
    "icons": "Extention_Logo_48x48.png",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Drive to Tumblr",
        "default_icon": "Extention_Logo_19x19.png",
        "default_popup": "button.html"
    }
}
```